# LaTeX, a0poster,tikz and multicols

Tags: latex, pdftex, a0poster

I'm using the multicol package inside an a0poster document class. I am trying out a 3 column layout for a portrait poster. I have a large tikz drawing that I want to put inside a figure environment inside a column. If I put the figure inside the multicols environment, the picture disappears. In fact, I can only get text to stick to the columns at all is to enclose it in a minipage and set the width to \columnwidth. But figure doesn't like being inside minipage, so that didn't work. What is going on here? The documentation for a0poster seems minimal at best.

So my question is, where can I find some guidance on how to use a0poster, or is there some better way of making an academic poster in LaTeX?

[When I tried to come up with a minimal example, things messed up even further, when I ran pdftex on the minimal code, it would make a big a0 page, but then when I tried to view it, it thought it was a4, so I could only see the top left corner of the page.]

Comment: are you sure you have all the necessary packages? the website says:     
* a0poster.cls and a0header.ps - the A0-poster header- and class-file (v1.21c)
* a0size.sty - the style-file for the correct sizes
* ...and you need the multicol, pstricks and pst-grad packages.

the website is here: http://andreas.welcomes-you.com/projects/a0poster/

Comment: ... and you realize that latex supports an ass-load of paper sizes with each document class: a0paper, a1paper, a2paper, and so on, that can be called in the document class: `\documentclass[a0paper,12pt]{book}`

Comment: a0poster isn't just about paper size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question is, *why* do you want to put the tikz drawing inside a figure?  Are you hoping it will float to the top of one column?  For a poster I would just use brute force and put `\break` and the tikz drawing in the places they need to go.

If I had to guess, I would guess that figures and multicols are not playing nicely together.  I suggest you try a similar example on a document of `article` class and ordinary size.

Comment: I guess it was in a figure because I C/Ped it from my article. Turns out sciposter is a better bet anyway, since that redefines figure to work with multicol on a poster.

Answer (score 1):

`\figure` won't work in a multicol-environment

But it should still work. Try putting this in the preamble:

```
\newcommand{\myfig}[3][0]{%<br/>
\includegraphics[width=#3,angle=#1]{#2}<br/>
\nobreak\medskip<br/>
}
```

and this too

```
\setcounter{figure}{1}<br/>
\newcommand{\mycaption}[1]{%<br/>
\vspace{5mm}<br/>
\begin{quote}<br/>
\textbf{\itshape Figure \arabic{figure}}: {\itshape #1}<br/>
\end{quote}<br/>
\vspace{10mm}<br/>
\stepcounter{figure}<br/>
}
```